# Sending messages from server to client c#

Tags: c#, tcp, client-server, listener, messaging

My client sends messages to the my server using tcp protocol (my server has a listener).
I'm trying to send messages back from the server to the client, but I'm not sure what do I need to add to the client in order to get those messages.
I tried looking it up, but I didn't understand how to implement it.

Could you please assist?

Answer (score 2):

It's the exact same process, but in reverse.

Comment: I didn't want to open a new question for this, but I have a quick follow up.  I'm just starting with TCP and I basically want communication back and forth regularly between client and server.  When I look up tutorials I see that the basic set is is the client sends and the server listens in 2 separate classes.  But realistically, following your answer, would I just one 1 class with ability to send AND receive and have 2 instances, 1 running under each machine?

Comment: That's entirely possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to receive messages independently (i.e. not in response to a request by the client), you need to make the client a TCP server, too. The client needs to implement exactly the same thing as the server you have now and the server needs to connect to the client.

Can't you use WCF, which supports callback contracts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a console example of a client server application using a network library see here http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/.

If you want a WPF application example then see here http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/